# Get latest records without matching condtion in mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to get latest records even though without matching the conditions in MYsql.

In example, I want to select data on 2013-01-20 by group by product type, but it doesn't match this condition, So it will get the latest date of those product type (2013-01-19 or 2013-01-15).

```
Coding:

Select date from tblproducttype where 
date=(select max(date) from tblproducttype group by type) where date='2013-01-20'


Table product type

ID  Type  Date
1   2     2013-01-20
2   2     2013-01-20
3   2     2013-01-14
4   3     2013-01-19
5   4     2013-01-16
6   4     2013-01-13
```

Result should be the following:

```
ID  Type  Date
1   2     2013-01-20
2   2     2013-01-20
4   3     2013-01-19
5   4     2013-01-16
```

For results, i want to combine the data for 2013-01-20 with the latest data for other products.

Finally, we can get only latest date of those product type.

How to do that in MYSQL?

Regards.

Comment: please post your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product_type p
JOIN (SELECT Type, MAX(Date) maxdate
      FROM prodct_type
      GROUP BY Type) m
ON p.Type = m.Type and p.Date = m.maxdate
```

The `m` subquery finds the latest date for each type. The join then finds all rows for each type on that date.

To filter out a condition, use a HAVING clause in the subquery:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product_type p
JOIN (SELECT Type, MAX(Date) maxdate
      FROM prodct_type
      GROUP BY Type
      HAVING maxdate != '2013-01-20') m
ON p.Type = m.Type and p.Date = m.maxdate
```

or a WHERE clause in the main query:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product_type p
JOIN (SELECT Type, MAX(Date) maxdate
      FROM prodct_type
      GROUP BY Type) m
ON p.Type = m.Type and p.Date = m.maxdate
WHERE maxDate != '2013-01-20'
```

Comment: if we set date condition date= 2013-01-20,but we list latest data of other product types too. so how to do this in subjquery?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "set date condition"? You mean you only want results on that date, instead of using the latest date for each type?

Comment: You don't need a subquery or join for that, just an ordinary WHERE clause.

Comment: I want to filter condition date=2013-01-20, but other product types that not equal this condition, i would like get latest data of those products type too. U got it?

Comment: So you don't want to get rows for type 1 or 2 in the results in your example?

Comment: No, your query is right, i want to set date condition as the following:SELECT p.*
FROM product_type p
JOIN (SELECT Type, MAX(Date) maxdate
      FROM prodct_type
      GROUP BY Type) m
ON p.Type = m.Type and p.Date = m.maxdate and p.date='2013-01-20'. it is possible to add condition but keep the same result as ur query.

Comment: I suspect what you want is a UNION, to combine the data for 2013-01-20 with the latest data for other products.

Comment: Could you update the question with the data and desired results, so I can tell the difference between this and what I already wrote.

Comment: Doesn't my first query give the desired result? I asked you to show data where the desired result is DIFFERENT from the result of my query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by aggregating the data to get the maximum date and then joining this information back to the original table:

```
select t.id, t.type, t.date
from t join
     (select type, max(date) as maxdate
      from t
      group by type
     ) tsum
     on t.type = tsum.type and t.date = tsum.maxdate
order by id;
```